# ODBC to SAP HANA connection timeout in Perl

Tags: perl, odbc, hana, unixodbc

Since I'm programming a Perl script to monitor the SAP HANA database, I'm experiencing problems with the connection timeout. I don't know how to set the timeout. This is my connection string:

```
use DBI;
use DBD::ODBC;
$dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:ODBC:dsn=$dsn");
```

Meanwhile in another script to monitor a Sybase database it works properly:

```
use DBI;

dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Sybase:server=$dbsvr;database=$dbname;".
               timeout=$timeout;"."loginTimeout=$timeout", $user, $pass);
```

I think the problem comes with the ODBC. Which is the way to implement a timeout using ODBC connection?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to set SQL_ATTR_LOGIN_TIMEOUT on the connection handle via DBD::ODBC. In any case, few ODBC drivers do anything with it. However, if you are on UNIX and using the unixODBC driver manager - see [Setting ODBC driver environment variables automatically](http://www.easysoft.com/developer/interfaces/odbc/linux.html#env_unixodbc)

You basically add "DMConnAttr = CONNECTION_ATTRIBUTE=value" to you odbc.ini file where CONNECTION_ATTRIBUTE is an ODBC connection attribute (e.g., SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT) and value is what you want to set it to.

Comment: Already tried and don't know why it doesn't work. It's like my unixODBC doesn't recognize it. Here my DSN configuration in "odbc.ini" file: `[TESTTIMEOUT]
Driver=/usr/sap/hdbclient/libodbcHDB.so
ServerNode=100....
DMConnAttr = SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT=10` I'm running a CentOS, don't  think this could be the issue. It always shows the error message after 63 seconds. This is the message: [unixODBC][SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB SO][HDBODBC] Communication link failure;-10709 Connection failed (RTE:[89006] System call 'connect' failed, rc=110:Expiró el tiempo de conexión) (SQL-08S01)

Answer (score 0):

It is commom to confused with connection and query timeout:

`DMStmtAttr = SQL_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT=2`

`DMConnAttr = SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT=2`

Connection may be ok but query response take more time than normal